# Outputting a textplot and qplot in same pdf or png in r

Tags: r, legend, ggplot2

I have a histogram produced using plot in the ggplot2 package:

[image]

and a table produced using textplot from the gplots package

[image]

I would like to display them in the same pdf or png if possible.

I have tried grid.arrange without luck. Any other suggestions? As each table is only 5 rows long I was also considering inserting it into the plot as a 'legend' or text-box in the margin of the qplot. Any advice on how to make this look good? Thanks for your ideas.

### SOLUTION##

In the end I went for and inset unfortunately my colour scheme looks worse...I have posted this issue as a new question.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `grid.table` to make the table, and then using that in `grid.arrange`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

g = tableGrob(iris[1:2, 1:2])

p = qplot(1:10, 1:10, geom = "blank") +
     annotation_custom(g) # as inset

grid.arrange(p, g, ncol=1) # stacked
ggsave("plot-table.pdf", arrangeGrob(p, g, ncol=1))
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the inset option in the end (I added it to the question). My next problem is that I need to get the segments of each bar to stand out better...they all just blur at the moment. Also I need to get the key scale direction the same as in the histogram..they are currently going the opposite direction which is confusing. Anyway, I started a new question for this so if you feel keen... :)

Comment: Please, is it also possible to add a title to the plotted table ?

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example with the gridExtra library

```
my_hist<-ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar()  
my_table<- tableGrob(head(diamonds)[,1:3],gpar.coretext = gpar(fontsize=8),gpar.coltext=gpar(fontsize=8), gpar.rowtext=gpar(fontsize=8))  
pdf("myplot.pdf")  
grid.arrange(my_hist,my_table, ncol=2)  
dev.off()
```

You can change the fontsizes in the table, and the size of the pdf: pdf("myplot.pdf",width=10, height = 6)
If you prefer a different arrangment, you might also need a blank panel:
blankPanel<-grid.rect(gp=gpar(col="white"))
[image]